# Non-deterministic corruption with lambdas in C++11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, lambda, c++11

Inspired by Herb Sutter's compelling lecture [Not your father's C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/-Not-Your-Father-s-C-), I decided to take another look at the latest version of C++ using Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010. I was particularly interested by Herb's assertion that C++ is "safe" because I hadn't heard how C++11 solved the well-known upwards funarg problem. From what I can tell, C++11 does nothing to solve this problem and, consequently, is not "safe".

You don't want to return a reference to a local variable because the local is allocated on a stack frame that will no longer exist after the function has returned and, therefore, the function will return a dangling pointer to allocated memory that will cause non-deterministic data corruption. C and C++ compilers know this and warn you if you try to return a reference or pointer to a local. For example, this program:

```
int &bar() {
  int n=0;
  return n;
}
```

causes Visual Studio 2010 to emit the warning:

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
```

However, lambdas in C++11 make it easy to capture a local variable by reference and return that reference, resulting in an equivalent dangling pointer. Consider the following function `foo` that returns a lambda function that captures the local variable `n` and returns it:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<int()> foo(int n) {
  return [&](){return n;};
}
```

This innocuous-looking function is memory unsafe and a source of corrupt data. Calling this function to get the lambda in one place and then invoking the lambda and printing its return value in another place gives this output for me:

```
1825836376
```

Moreover, Visual Studio 2010 gives no warning.

This looks like a really serious design flaw in the language to me. Even the simplest refactoring could make a lambda cross stack frames, silently introducing non-deterministic data corruption. Yet there seems to be precious little information about this problem (e.g. searching for "upwards funarg" and C++ on StackOverflow gives no hits). Are people aware of this? Is anyone working on a solution or describing workarounds?

Comment: The lack of warning is the only problem I see here, but it's not exactly a design flaw in the language.

Comment: I don't have a solution to this but I guess it's just another way to really hurt yourself using C/C++ - "With great power, comes great responsibility" ;D

Comment: @CarstenKönig, and, thanks to OP, forewarned is forearmed :)

Comment: Yes, people are aware of this. (See f.e. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/01/29/perils-of-lambda-capture.aspx). It's not any more a design flaw than allowing you to return a ref to a local without mandating that the compiler fail the build. (And if you run that lambda before returning from the function, which can be useful, the capture is valid). You get lots of power, as others have said, use it carefully.

Comment: "You get lots of power". What do you mean by "power" there?

Comment: @Mat: Note that the advice "never capture locals by reference" from the blog post you cite implies that you should either deep copy locals (which is slow) or hoist them to an outer scope that is live for the entire duration of their use (which increases floating garbage).

Comment: Oh, and deep copying only really works with immutable collections and there is no efficient way to implement them without garbage collection. So the only practicable option is to hoist to outer scopes and that's going to introduce synchronization problems if your program is parallel or concurrent.

Comment: How is that any different than trying to capture a local in non-lambda context?

Comment: @Mat Environment capture is specific to lambdas so I don't know what you mean by "capture in a non-lambda context".

Comment: Return a reference/pointer to automatic storage, hang on to a temp with a non-const ref, keep a member ref of an object whose lifetime is not bound to this one ... all things you can already do without lambdas.

Comment: `e.g. searching for "upwards funarg" and C++ on StackOverflow gives no hits` I've been using C++ for a while, and I've never even heard of the word "funarg" before, let alone "upwards funargs". I've heard of dangling references before, but not "funarg". Where does this term come from?

Comment: @Nicol The term "funarg" predates C++ by several decades. It was used to describe this same problem when closures with lexical scope were being added to Lisp circa 1970. The solution was to heap allocate and garbage collect. Pascal (1968) solved the upwards funarg problem by restricting passing of functions to downwards only, i.e. you can pass by argument but not return in result.

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to lambdas, you can do tons of bad things when it comes to lifetime (and you've noted at least one case of it). While C++11 might be safer in several respects compared to C++03, C++ hasn't put an emphasis on memory-safety.

That's not to say that C++ *doesn't* want to be safe, but I'd say the usual philosophy "don't pay for what you don't use" usually gets in the way of adding safety guards (not considering things like the halting problem which might prevent issuing diagnostics for all invalid programs). If you can solve the upwards funarg problem *while* not affecting the performance of every other case then the Standard Committee is interested. (I don't mean that in a mean way, I think it's an interesting and *hard* problem.)

Since you seem to be doing some catch-up, then the wisdom of authors (and others) so far is to generally refrain from using the by-reference catch-all capture for lambda expressions (e.g. `[&, foo, bar]`), and to be careful with by-reference capture in general. You can think of the capture-list of a lambda-expression as another place in C++ where you have to be careful with lifetimes; or another view is to consider a lambda-expression as a object literal notation for functors (they're specified that way in fact). You have to be careful when you design a class type with regards to lifetime already:

```
struct foo {
    explicit foo(T& t)
        : ref(t)
    {}

    T& ref;
};

foo make_foo()
{
    T t;
    // Bad
    return foo { t };
    // Not altogether different from
    // return [&t] {};
}
```

In this respect lambda expressions don't change the status quo when it comes to writing 'obvious' bad code, and they inherit all the preexisting caveats.

Comment: Another big difference seems to be that C++11 does not automate the capture of environment variables so, in that sense, you must explicitly state that you want to capture a variable wrongly so it is no worse. I had thought that it was all automated which seemed even more dangerous. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you cannot simply work in a C++ project of any sort of complexity if you try to keep yourself blissfully unaware of memory handling. There are hundreds of languages that aim for this sort of paradigm a lot better. There is a reason why C++ does not have garbage collection; it really does not fit the scenarios where you want to use C++

Being said that, in your lambda example, a simple change will make your lambda example completely safe:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<int()> foo(int n) {
  return [=](){return n;}; //now n is copied by value
}
```

Comment: "you cannot simply work in a C++ project of any sort of complexity if you try to keep yourself blissfully unaware of memory handling". I agree completely but this leaves me baffled by Herb's assertion that modern C++ is "safe". There's nothing safe about this...

Comment: There is no language, that is completely safe. With enough knowledge, you can break every language either by using its internal structures or by using 3rd party native libraries.
Moreover, try to return a pointer to local variable. It's as dangerous as returning a reference, but I'd guess, that it won't raise any compiler warnings at all...
The new C++ is safe in terms, that it allows you to write safe code more easily than previous versions. For instance, you can return shared_ptr to dynamically allocated instance of std::function and everything shall work as charm.